# How to update windows time zones list?

Tags: windows-server-2012, .net

I have front-end and back-end systems using the `System.TimeZoneInfo` for retrieving Timezone by ID.
There are several time-zones missing from the back-end machine (running windows Server 2012) and I'm not sure how to get an update.

For instance *"Line Islands Standard Time"*
Using `System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(String id)` I'm getting this exception
`System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: The time zone ID 'Line Islands Standard Time' was not found on the local computer.`

Both systems have .net framework 4.8 installed.

Comment: Does the Line Islands Standard Time entry appear when you use `tzutil /l` to list them all? And does it appear in the registry, under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\ ? That'll help narrow down whether the time zone is missing or if System.TimeZoneInfo is having anther problem with it.

Comment: According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3013386/update-including-december-2013-and-august-2014-cumulative-time-zone-up, the Line Islands entry was added in August 2014, under update KB2981580, discussed here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2981580. Perhaps your server never got that one. It can be downloaded from that KB2981580 page.

Comment: @DougDeden It is missing from the tzutil /l list, I'll try to get that update